# Using a Leaflet realtime layer in a markercluster group

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer, leaflet.markercluster

I'm using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html) in combination with the [realtime](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime) and [markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugins in order to show markers, that get live updated on a map. 
The plugins work great independent from each other, but the problem arises when I want to cluster the realtime layer using the markercluster features.

Code sample for the realtime layer in which I convert the json to markers, asign a custom icon and apply some onEachFeature function:

```
realtimeLayer = L.realtime({
    url: 'someURL',
    crossOrigin: true,
    type: 'json'
}, {
    interval: 3 * 1000,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: customIcon
        });
    }
});
```

What I'm able to do with non-realtime marker layers is to create a markercluster group and add the layer to it, so the markers get clustered like this:

```
var clusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup();
clusterGroup.addLayer(someLayer);
```

However when I add the realtimeLayer to the clustergroup, the clustering is not applied, or the marker do net get loaded at all. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `container` option to your realtime object options.

From the official Leaflet Realtime documentation:

> L.Realtime can also use other layer types to display the results, for
>   example it can use a MarkerClusterGroup from Leaflet MarkerCluster:
>   pass a LayerGroup (or any class that implements addLayer and
>   removeLayer) to L.Realtime's container option. (This feature was added
>   in version 2.1.0.)
>
> - https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime#overview

So after you initialize your cluster group and add it to map:

```
var clusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup();
clusterGroup.addTo(map);
```

You can then pass the clusterGroup object to your realtime object in the container option:

```
realtimeLayer = L.realtime({
    url: 'someURL',
    crossOrigin: true,
    type: 'json'
}, {
    container: clusterGroup
    interval: 3 * 1000,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: customIcon
        });
    }
});
```

Now when you add the realtime object to the map, it should cluster correctly:

```
realtimeLayer.addTo(map)
```

The official Leaflet Realtime repo has an example for doing what you want with the added option of grouping multiple L.Realtime objects: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime/blob/master/examples/earthquakes.js